# How to fix Absolute Path Traversal in MavenWrapperDownloader.java

Tags: java, maven, maven-wrapper

After a security scan, I get the error *Absolute Path Traversal* in the file:

https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper/blob/master/.mvn/wrapper/MavenWrapperDownloader.java

Line 50:
File baseDirectory = new File(args[0]);

The MavenWrapperDownloader.java belong actually to apache ... is there a new version of the file from where I will not get an error?

One option I found (https://portswigger.net/web-security/file-path-traversal) is to use

```
File file = new File(BASE_DIRECTORY, userInput);
if (file.getCanonicalPath().startsWith(BASE_DIRECTORY)) {
    // process file
}
```

But in the java class they are already checking:

```
File mavenWrapperPropertyFile = new File(baseDirectory, MAVEN_WRAPPER_PROPERTIES_PATH);
        String url = DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD_URL;
        if(mavenWrapperPropertyFile.exists()) {
...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: First you claimed that MavenWrapperDownloader.java belongs to Apache? You mean that file has an Apache License?  If you think it's necessary to change that create pull request on the takari/maven-wrapper repo ... For Maven 4.X will get a maven wrapper (https://github.com/apache/maven/tree/master/maven-wrapper)
Does the security scan happen in a corporate environment?

Comment: yes it has an Apache license, and yes the security scan happens in a corporate environment. So, you mean that I can use the maven wrapper 4.X (MavenWrapperMain) and performs the same as the MavenWrapperDownloader?

Comment: No you can't use wrapper 4.X because it's not yet released in a 4.X. Apart from that I don't understand why using a wrapper in a corporate environment. and you can exclude that problem in your security scan in your environment....

Comment: yes, i also wondered that I wanted to have another opinion so I can discuss it internally with the team. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the below code worked which is part of [Apache commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#normalize-java.lang.String-:%7E:text=Method%20Detail-,normalize,-public%20static%C2%A0)

**FilenameUtils.normalize(baseDirectory)**

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
...

File mavenWrapperPropertyFile = new File(FilenameUtils.normalize(baseDirectory), MAVEN_WRAPPER_PROPERTIES_PATH);
        String url = DEFAULT_DOWNLOAD_URL;
        if(mavenWrapperPropertyFile.exists()) {
    ...
```